# Windows 10 - How to remove a stray popover in the foreground

Tags: windows-10

This happens from time to time - some Windows application will show a popover when I mouse over a button or action, and for some reason it never goes away.   This stays in the foreground of any application, so it ends up obscuring some screen real estate. (See "Close" in attached image)

Even if I close every open application, it stays there.

Is there a way to cause the desktop to refresh?
Or any other troubleshooting suggestion short of rebooting?

[image]

Comment: Change the screen resolution to something else and then switch it back?

Comment: Tried but the popover remained.

Comment: You can refresh your Desktop by right clicking on it and clicking refresh.

Comment: Thanks @Confuzing.  Tried that but didn't clear the popover.

Comment: You could try restarting explorer.exe although I really wouldn't expect that to work either. If you open Task Manager and under the Processes tab find "explorer.exe", right click on it and select restart. This will close all open File Explorers and restart your taskbar and start menu.

Comment: Found this command that may be helpful. `tskill dwm` You can do Win+R to open run menu and run it. Supposed to reset the desktop window manager.

Comment: Another good suggestion.  Still no change, alas.